# validation script losing characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

the script below should validate the user input each typed character at once, but it's losing characters, and it's always the character after a symbol (ex.: if I type `14121982` for a date field, I get `14/_2/_9822` in the textfield, and `14/_2/_982` internally). Also, this difference between the content of textfield and the content my intenal variable is a issue.

**jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/f8U4c/41/

**code**

```
var counter;
var tam;
var str;
var regex;

$('.valida').each(function(){

    $(this).on('focus', function(e){
        regex = $(this).attr('pattern');

        counter = 0;
        tam = size_of(regex);
        str = generate_string(regex, tam);

        $(this).val(str);
    });

    $(this).on('keypress', function(e){
        var tecla = e.which;
        var tecla2 = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
        var t = type_of(regex, counter);

        if(typeof tecla == t) {
            str = replaceAt(str, counter, tecla2);
            //counter++;
        } else {
            if(t != 'number' && t != 'string') {
                str = replaceAt(str, counter, t);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        counter++;

        result = $("<div>");
        result.append( "counter = "+counter+"<br>" );
        result.append( "tecla2 = "+tecla2+"<br>" );
        result.append( "typeof tecla2 = "+typeof tecla+"<br>" );
        result.append( "typeof t = "+t+"<br>" );
        result.append( "str = "+str+"<br>" );
        $("#result").empty().append(result);

        $(this).val(str);
    });

});
```

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

Comment: One problem is that in "generate_string" you use "tam" instead of "tamanho" but I don't know if that's the only problem.

Comment: You need to call `e.preventDefault()` in the "keypress" event handler or else the browser will add the character to the end of the value *after* your code updates the value in the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more tryouts, I finally get a working code:

**jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/klebermo/f8U4c/78/

**code**

```
$('.valida').each(function(){

    $(this).on('focus', function(e){
        regex = $(this).attr('pattern');

        counter = 0;
        tam = size_of(regex);
        str = generate_string(regex, tam);

        $(this).val(str);
    });

    $(this).on('keypress', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var tecla = e.which;

        if(tecla >= 48 && tecla <= 57)
            var tecla2 = tecla - 48;
        else
            var tecla2 = String.fromCharCode(tecla);

        result = $("<div>");
        result.append( "tecla = "+tecla+"<br>" );

        var t = type_of(regex, counter);

        if(counter < tam) {
            if(t != 'number' && t != 'string') {
                str = replaceAt(str, counter, t);
                counter++;
            }

            t = type_of(regex, counter);

            if(typeof tecla2 == t) {
                result.append( "tecla2 = "+tecla2+"<br>" );
                str = replaceAt(str, counter, tecla2);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        result.append( "counter = "+counter+"<br>" );
        $("#result").empty().append(result);

        $(this).val(str);
    });

});
```